# HG Update Branch merge required

Tags: mercurial

Maybe I am missing something important here but I want to switch to another branch without first committing what I currently have. I realize I can use `hg update -C` and simply drop the current changes as well but this is not what I want to do either.

My problem is that I have several branches I am working on simultaneously and do not want to fill up my history with a large number of small commits. Is there a middle ground in which I can store my current branch without committing each little change I make in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the options of the [shelve](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension) option already mentioned, and having lots of small changesets in your history, you could use the [collapse](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) extension to take those small changesets and combine them into a single larger changeset. This is ideal for exactly the scenario you're describing - fixing typos, etc.

With Mercurial 2.1 and later the collapse extension will respect [phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases), so you won't inadvertently collapse changesets that you've published.

In general though, I'd advocate doing all those little changes on a separate named branch and then just merge into your default (or other feature) branch when you're happy.

Comment: BTW, the collapse extension can be largely replaced now by `hg rebase --collapse -r <range> --dest <parent of first rev in range>`.

Answer (score 2):

The [shelve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension) can do what you want:

From the page:

Temporarily stash away changes. You can select the exact hunks 
of changes you want to shelve.

> hg shelve

Temporarily stash away changes. All hunks will automatically be
selected.

> hg shelve --all

Get the changes back into the workdir.

> hg unshelve

If you use the --name option you can shelve different changes on different shelves.

However, what's wrong with lots of little commits? If the changes stand by themselves they probably deserve a commit, you really don't want to put multiple issues in a checkin if you want to keep your sanity, particularly if you're going to merge features into other repos later.

Comment: In many cases my commits consist of spelling mistakes and style changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have each branch checked-out in it's own clone. You can switch between them without needing to do anything.